# Is passing a private function to another class considered proper in oop?

Tags: actionscript-3, oop

I have a private function in class A. Class A creates an instance of class B and sends it a reference to this private function. Class B later uses this function.
It all works fine, but I'm not sure this is proper OOP.
I'm doing it in AS3.

Comment: The whole business of juggling *functions* seems pretty un-OOP-ish. (Which isn't necessarily a bad thing.)

Comment: What is the need of doing this? How exactly are you using this function? Shouldn't it be rather a *static function* in that case?

Comment: class A represents a log in page where you enter a user name and a password and then click a submit button. Clicking that button disables it and creates an instance of class B which goes to the data base to check details. If the details are wrong, class B needs to enable the submit button. But, the function that is related to the submit button is in class A, which is why I pass a reference of it to class B.

Comment: the function can't be static cause it uses non-static variables and non static other functions. If it were static, I wouldn't need to pass it to the other class. I could just call it: A.theFunction();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is proper.  You'll probably have a couple of people who say otherwise, but I'll have to disagree with them.

Something you'll see a LOT of in AS3 is event listeners:

```
someObject.addEventListener(someEventType, someFunction);
```

It is very common for `someFunction` to be a private function in a different class than `someObject's`, and it is considered a completely proper practice.  And since this isn't a violation of good OOP - and it is widely considered proper - the same should hold for vanilla callbacks.  Callbacks / event listeners are something that really does need to be generally allowed in programming, even OOP languages.

What would be bad is if each class knew about the other, and you had both of them calling each other's functions instead of using event listeners or other callbacks.

Comment: +1 it is very oop. Also to note about event listeners is they come with a lot of over head where assigning a function for a callback wont have that. But keep in mind the functional route will make it harder to decouple the class later on.